# Dialogflow: Call third party api from webhook and wait for response

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am creating a chatbot which have an intent with a payment link. So on trigger of this intent, I made call from webhook fulfillment to third party api which takes approx 20secs to respond. But in this period of time my response is timed out as it is limited to 5 sec from google.

Can you please suggest what approach should I follow. I just want to wait for approx 20 sec to respond.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one option is to keep the conversation alive using events (generated by the webhook) which trigger dedicated intents.

When a payment must be performed the webhook starts a background process to deal with the 3rd party payment API, and sleep for 4-5 sec, after that generates an event (setFollowupEvent PAYMENT_IN_PROGRESS). This event is associated to a DialogFlow Intent which fires as soon as the event is sent back to the platform.
At this point you have another incoming webhook call: check status of the payment, if it is still in progress (likely after 5 sec) then sleep 4-5 sec and send another event (setFollowupEvent PAYMENT_IN_PROGRESS_2) which produces the same workflow.

There are so many times you can do this (I think a max of 3), so you need to cater for the  fact that the payment does not terminate in time (fallback scenario).
A smart option could be to keep engaging the user with the conversation, not always easy, depending on what your chatbot is about.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't.

The longer answer is that you need to think about this as a conversation. If you asked someone a question, and didn't get any response from them for 20 seconds - that would be pretty uncomfortable, wouldn't it?

Instead, we have come up with ways to compensate for that silence. In a physical conversation, people may engage with you and ask you questions to fill the time. If you're on the phone, they may play hold music. Or we may end the conversation for now and tell them later when there is a result.

When building an Action, we have similar parallels that may work better or worse based on our exact needs.

**Engaging in conversation**

One approach is that when we get the request from the user, we do two things:

1. Start a task that will execute the query and save the results in a separate "answer database", indexed against the user, a session ID, or some other temporary id we can generate and use later.
2. While the query is running, we reply to the user saying we're working on it, and asking them another question.

Then, when they reply with their answer to this other question, we can check if we have an answer for them in the database. If we do, we'll reply with it. If not, we'll repeat step 2 until we do.

This approach works well if we either have other questions to ask, or if we're in a good place to "make small talk". Picture booking an airline reservation - while we look up flights, we may want to ask if they prefer window or aisle seats (Which we'd need to ask later) or make small talk by asking if they're traveling for business or leisure.

**Using "hold music"**

A variant of this allows us to play some hold music while we're processing the answer.

Instead of asking a question in step 2 above, we reply with a [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/rich-responses#media_responses) that plays 20 seconds or so of music. When the music completes, our fulfillment webhook will be sent a `MEDIA_STATUS` event and we can either return the information from the answer database, or say we're still working on it and play more music.

This is less conversational, but may work better if we don't actually have anything to say in the meantime.

**Sending a notification**

If the response may take a very long time, then it may just be best to let them do other things and to [send a notification](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications) or a text or email when you have a result. These cases, however, require the user to have registered with you in some way and are probably more appropriate if you have a long-standing relationship with the user.

**Summary**

You should be returning results as quickly as you can to keep it feeling like a conversation. When you can't, consider other means, just like how we would consider what it would be like if we were talking to another person.